# php and twig syntax

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have the following code to extract the username of an owner object. The Owner object is essentially the owner of the shop. Here's how it's defined in the Shop class.

```
 /**
     * Set owner
     *
     * @param User $owner
     * @return Shop
     */
    public function setOwner(User $owner = null)
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get owner
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function getOwner()
    {
        return $this->owner;
    }
    /**
```

As you can see the owner returns a User object. However when I do .username to the User class I always get undefined. Why is this?

```
"<%= '/profile/'+item.get('shop').owner.username %>">
```

When I do the following:

```
 "<%= '/profile/'+item.get('shop').name %>">
```

it prints out just fine.

Here's some more code on the Shop:

```
class Shop
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Exclude()
     * @ORM\Column(name="isVisible", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isVisible = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\ShopLogo", mappedBy="shop", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    protected $shoplogo;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Shope name should not be blank")
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, unique=true)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * Assert\NotBlank(message="Description should not be blank")
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=350, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $description = "";


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="tags", type="text",nullable=true)
     */
    protected $tags = "";

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="shop", cascade={"remove","persist"})
     */
    protected $products;


    /**
     * @Exclude()
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Shopious\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="shop")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $owner;

    /**
     * @Exclude()
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\PaymentInfo", inversedBy="shop", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="paymentInfo_id", referencedColumnName="id" , onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $paymentInfo;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\ShopTestimonial", mappedBy="shop", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    protected $testimonials;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->shopname;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function initialisation()
    {
        $this->shoplogo = new ShopLogo();
        $this->shoplogo->setShop($this);

    }
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set owner
     *
     * @param User $owner
     * @return Shop
     */
    public function setOwner(User $owner = null)
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get owner
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function getOwner()
    {
        return $this->owner;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Set shopname
     *
     * @param string $shopname
     * @return Shop
     */
    public function setName($shopname)
    {
        $this->name = $shopname;

        //return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shopname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Shop
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }


    /**
     * Add products
     *
     * @param Product $products
     * @return Shop
     */
    public function addProduct(Product $products)
    {
        $this->products[] = $products;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove products
     *
     * @param Product $products
     */
    public function removeProduct(Product $products)
    {
        $this->products->removeElement($products);
    }

    /**
     * Get products
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    public function getPaymentInfo()
    {
        return $this->paymentInfo;
    }

    public function setPaymentInfo(\Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\PaymentInfo $paymentInfo)
    {
        $this->paymentInfo = $paymentInfo;
    }


    /**
     * Set tags
     *
     * @param string $tags
     * @return Shop
     */
    public function setTags($tags)
    {
        $this->tags = $tags;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tags
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    /**
     * Set shoplogo
     *
     * @param Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\ShopLogo $shoplogo
     * @return Shop
     */
    public function setShoplogo(\Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\ShopLogo $shoplogo = null)
    {
        $this->shoplogo = $shoplogo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shoplogo
     *
     * @return Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\ShopLogo 
     */
    public function getShoplogo()
    {
        return $this->shoplogo;
    }

    /**
     * Add testimonials
     *
     * @param \Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\ShopTestimonial $testimonials
     * @return Shop
     */
    public function addTestimonial(\Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\ShopTestimonial $testimonials)
    {
        $this->testimonials[] = $testimonials;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove testimonials
     *
     * @param \Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\ShopTestimonial $testimonials
     */
    public function removeTestimonial(\Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\ShopTestimonial $testimonials)
    {
        $this->testimonials->removeElement($testimonials);
    }

    /**
     * Get testimonials
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getTestimonials()
    {
        return $this->testimonials;
    }

    /**
     * Set isVisible
     *
     * @param boolean $isVisible
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setIsVisible($isVisible)
    {
        $this->isVisible = $isVisible;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isVisible
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIsVisible()
    {
        return $this->isVisible;
    }

}
```

Some code of fetching the data values:

```
public function getItemsAction()
    {
        try{
            $query = $this->getRequest()->query;
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $items = $em->getRepository('ShopiousMainBundle:Product')->filterBy(
                    $query->get('category'), 
                    $query->get('tag'), 
                    $query->get('size'), 
                    $query->get('price'), 
                    $query->get('shop'), 
                    $query->get('sort'),
                    $query->get('page')
                );

            return $this->Json($items);
        }catch(\Exception $ex){
            return $this->Json($ex->getMessage(),false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: give more details on the object (given class is incomplete)

Comment: @IOIOMAD you mean the Shop class? i.e: the Owner object? Copy pasted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing it is because their is not data for the relationship.  It looks like you probably have an item that you are calling a method on to get another object and then calling another method on that object to get yet another object.  Since the first call is a proxy object it probably doesn't load the second proxy object data with it.  If you look at the data in the data outside the template like in the controller I am guessing it isn't defined there.  you might want to make sure that the data is loaded prior to getting to the view.  I think that the root of the problem is the initial relationship.

To help you might post some of your controller code where you are getting fetching the data or setting the values.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like class Owner's name is stored into variable "name", not "username"

Comment: so item.get('shop').owner should return you a User object, and inside the User object there is username

Answer (score 0):

i think   `protected   $username;`  doesnot exist only    `protected $name;`

if you want

> "<%= '/profile/'+item.get('shop').owner.username %>">
>   then change

add this to you class first

```
 protected   $username[]; 


public function addUsers(User $user = null)
{
   array_push($this->username, $user);

    return $this->username;
}


public function getUsers()
{
   return $this->username;
}
```

or a single user

```
protected   $username; 

public function addUsers(User $user = null)
{
   $this->username= $user;

    return $this->username;
}


public function getUsers()
{
   return $this->username;
}
```

Comment: I changed the question, what works is  '/profile/'+item.get('shop').name

Comment: ya $username is undefined for a call  $name is defined for .owner.name  read my answer buddy!

Comment: I wanted the shop's user username, not the shop username. Re-read my question again, I edited it

Comment: does username want to be array?